# How to remove element from a list in matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to build Nim "mathematical game of strategy" in Python, I have problem with removing element from specific list from the matrix, I started with getting game mode from user and then start removing elements.

```
def RemoveMatches(Stacks,StackNum,Matches):  
    if not_empty(Stacks[StackNum]):
        lenStack=len(Stacks[StackNum])
        try:  
            val=int(Matches)
        except ValueError:
            print ("Wrong input,try only with numbers")
            return False
        if val>lenStack:
            print "try again with smaller number"
            return False
        else :
            for i in range(Matches):
                Stacks[StackNum].pop()
            return True
    else:
        print "Stack that you have chose is already empty,try other satck"
        return False
```

`Stacks` is the matrix that i build in main.
`StackNum`number of list that i want to remove from it elements.
`Matches` number of elements that i want to remove.

There is another function called `ManageGame` which control user's input "if it's 2 players or 1, getting `StackNum`/Matches":

```
def ManageGame(Stack,gameMode):
    if gameMode=='2':
        while(lastDot(Stack)):
            stackNum,matchesNum=raw_input('select number of the Stack and number of Matches between 1-10. keep a space between two numbers:').split(' ')

            check=RemoveMatches(Stack,int(stackNum),int(matchesNum))
            if check:
                DrawStacks(Stack)
            else:
                print "try again."
```

`lastDot(Stack)` is a function which checks if the matrix has more then 1 Dot.

The **problem** is when I'm trying to remove number of elements from StackNum I get somthing like this:
from:

[image]

When I type `StackNum=1,Matches=2` I get:

[image]

Somehow I remove 2 Dots from each matrix line, I cannot see the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The return in the line:

```
for i in range(Matches):
    Stacks[StackNum].pop()
    return True
```

is situated in the wrong location. you have to move it after the `for`.
Otherwise, after the first iteration it will exit and not run all the iterations:

```
for i in range(Matches):
    Stacks[StackNum].pop()
return True
```

Comment: I made a mistake here i wrote the code as your answer looks although it didnt work it gives the same output as it shown in pictures, thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

the problem here with the list `l=[]`,here how I build my matrix:

```
l=[]
tmp=[]
for i in range(10):
    l.append('*')
for i in range(5):
    tmp.append(l)
```

python works with pointers so I'm appending same pointer for tmp, when I make a change to one of them the rest going to be the same .
Here how I did solve it :

```
for i in range(5):  
    tmp.append(10)
```

When I want to pop an element I subtract **Matches** number.